# C# Timer class Change(dueDate, period)

Tags: c#

i have go through the msdn library about this timer class change function ,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148.aspx

public bool Change(
    int dueTime,
    int period
)

But i do not understand what is the period parameter for.

i also try to create a sample to see what it for but seems like it is doing nothing

```
Timer JobTime = new Timer(timer =>
        {
            try
            {
                WriteLog(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "TestJobTimer"); //Save invoke time to file

                ((Timer)timer).Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string stop = ex.Message;
            }
        });
        JobTime.Change(0, 0);
```

Base on this sample , what i get is the timer will repeat every 5 second , thus what is the PERIOD paramenter for ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you happen to **Read Remarks** *The callback method is invoked once after dueTime elapses, and thereafter each time the time interval specified by period elapses....*

Comment: @V4Vendetta I think he doesn't understand the definition of period.  Look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function

Comment: Your Change(0, 0) call prevents the timer from ever starting.

Answer (score 10):

**dueTime** shows when the first event will be fired,

**period** how often after that

in your case the first event will be fired after 5 second then after every 20 seconds

**EDIT**

As far as you are calling your timer change with 0,0, it starts impatiently and on timer tick call you change it to fire after 5 seconds every 20 second, that's why event fires every 5 seconds

If you want to fire event every 20 seconds after 5 seconds, remove timer change from handler, and start timer only once like this

```
    Timer JobTime = new Timer(timer =>
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "TestJobTimer"); //Save invoke time to file
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string stop = ex.Message;
        }
    });
    JobTime.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: but base on the Write File , the jobTime run every 5 sec , instead of the first time 5 sec than follow by 20 sec

Answer (score 2):

DueTime = time until first deployment

Period = amount of time after due time for next deployment, and amount of time for each subsequent deployment.

Comment: but base on the Write File , the jobTime run every 5 sec , instead of the first time 5 sec than follow by 20 sec